# What are the security implications of a user account with no password on linux?

Tags: linux, security, password

It is possible to log in to an account without a password from a virtual terminal when the password is empty. On my system(Arch Linux), logging in with `su` and an empty password simply gives a wrong password notification.

Can a program log in "directly"(without using `su`) with empty password?

Note that this is a "default" Linux installation, without `sudo`,`sshd` or anything of the type. This also does not take into someone malicious physically logging in from the keyboard, since physical access is total compromise anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to have an empty password? Maybe what you are doing can be achieved with either a locked account or with a password.

Comment: @Tigger Why would you want to type a password when don't have to?

Comment: How do you connect your remote vitual terminal if there is no sshd or anything?

Comment: @jlliagre Might have screwed up my terminology but what I mean by virtual terminal is the the things you get when you press Ctrl-Alt-F*

Comment: Then you have physical access to the keyboard which you seem to rule out in your question.

Comment: @jlliagre Me logging in does not count as compromise...

Comment: Still unclear to me. How can a program be launched without someone having access to the keyboard ? and what do you mean with "the same doesn't seem to work with su" ? Is your question "can I run a program that substitutes its identity without using su" ?

Comment: @jlliagre I have access to the keyboard, however I may run an untrusted program with user privileges once in a while. My root account has no password, and as far as I can observe it's not possible to log in with no password except for from the tty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the security implications of a user account with no password on linux?

That will make brute force attacks very efficient as they generally start with testing an empty password. The implications depend on how the system is configured. Some systems and services might not allow login using a passwordless account (e.g. [pam_unix **nullok** option](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/x263.html#AEN295)), or restrict such logins to some devices (e.g. see pam_unix **nullok_secure** option and [/etc/securetty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/securetty.5.html)).

> Can a program log in "directly"(without using su) with empty password?

A suid program can do it. A regular program might depending on the OS and on whether it is called from a login shell or not.